# Sometimes do not get network drive maps in Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, group-policy, mappeddrive

I have a user that has a AD (Windows 2003) loginscript that maps a number of drives. The user has to traverse an external network to login to the domain. It is a pretty reliable connection but it's sometimes slow.

Here's how the loginscript is mapping drives:

**net use x: \server\share /PERSISTENT:YES**

Sometimes she logs in and no drives show up in my computer. The /PERSISTENT switch should make these drives permanent, but this is not the case. In fact, loginscripts shouldn't even be necessary if you use this switch.

I also set the group policy option for her computer:

**computer config\admin templates\system\logon\always wait for the network at computer startup and logon**

to enabled. This slows down her startup but decreased the frequency of there being missing drives.

I have windows 7 ent. on my machine and I reboot with the network cable unplugged and my drives show up still. Does anyone know what could cause these drives to disappear? Is there a setting or registry key I'm missing? Another GPO setting to try?

Comment: i have the same issue w/ windows 7 business and file shares on a samba server. I had assume it was a samba problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar issues with lower drive letters ie f: g:, etc. If there is a local drive such as a usb device that is plugged in it will take prescidence over the mapped drive letter and cause problems even after it is unplugged, until the machine is rebooted.

Comment: I've seen problems like this too in other situations. I forgot about this possibility, but our network drive letters start at h: and the user only has a c: and d: drive. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You also going to want to configure [slow link detection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781031(v=ws.10).aspx) and behavior in GPO for any users/computers that will be traversing an unreliable/slow network.

With just the default settings configured, scripts will *not* be processed over a slow link.

Comment: I'm using login scripts defined in the user object. We are gradually switching over to gpo loginscripts. Thanks.

Comment: @James Not sure what that means. You should still configure these settings on any computer that would be processing GPOs over a slow link.

Comment: Sorry meant that I'm not using gpo login scripts right now. I'm trying to work in gpos into our infrastructure more little by little.

Comment: Ah, well if you're not using them for drive maps, don't start! Use Group Policy Preferences for print and drive maps!

Comment: Why not do gpo login scripts? Thanks for bringing up the gpo prefs, I have to look into this more. We don't have 2008 DCs though so I don't think it's doable :(

Comment: You should be able to configure those policies using the GPMC from a Windows 7 computer without having 2008 DCs. Microsoft is pushing people to get rid of logon scripts and use preferences instead. Item-Level Targetting alone makes GPP worth using over logon scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In the system policy editor you can set the system to run a batch file at startup.   That should be one way you could fix if you cant find the real answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know there are ways to run batch files from registry/gpo. I'm looking to map the drives without them disappearing. Is there something quirky going on with Windows 7 in terms losing drives. I think I may give this command a shot tomorrow:  NET CONFIG SERVER /AUTODISCONNECT:-1

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the login script/batch file runs before the network is ready. In your login script/batch file, first line, ping the server.  This will cause a delay in mapping the drives until the network is fully ready to map the drives.

Comment: He has already enabled the GPO to wait for network connectivity. That would render this approach redundant. Plus, I'd kind of kludgy anyway :)